# Batch script for loop

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have a problem with for loop in batch script.
When I try:

```
for /f "delims=;" %g in ('dir') do echo %g%
```

i see this

```
'dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Did I miss somethig? Why windows command doesn't work?

Comment: The `dir` needs to go between backticks. See the output of `help for`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Only with `"usebackq"`. Otherwise single quotes are fine.

Comment: I guess your batch file contains more code than only this line? maybe the error is caused somewhere else...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `%comspec%` variable has been nulled or changed and it can't find `cmd.exe`

Test this to see the error, and remove line 2 for it to work fine, on a working machine.

```
@echo off
set comspec=c:\aaa
for /f "delims=;" %%g in ('dir') do echo %%g
pause
```

Something that is very interesting is that the path to cmd.exe is cached.
The two scripts below are the same with only the order of the commands changed

This batch file will fail with both `for` commands

```
@echo off
set comspec=c:\aaa
for /f "delims=;" %%g in ('dir') do echo %%g
pause
set "comspec=%windir%\System32\cmd.exe"
for /f "delims=;" %%g in ('dir') do echo %%g
pause
```

and this batch file will work with both `for` commands.

```
@echo off
set "comspec=%windir%\System32\cmd.exe"
for /f "delims=;" %%g in ('dir') do echo %%g
pause
set comspec=c:\aaa
for /f "delims=;" %%g in ('dir') do echo %%g
pause
```

Comment: Maybe thats the problem. I will try to check comspec in runtime

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. You get all kinds of problems iterating over `dir` output with `for /f`. Instead just use

```
for %g in (*) do @echo %g
```

Comment: okej, but when a use any other command like `git status` Why I get same error? Git is added to path and I can use it form cmd without problems, but when i use it in loop I i get this message.

Comment: Iterating over dir in a for /f loop is perfectly fine if you use `dir /b`.

Comment: @SomethingDark: Have fun with spaces. You can solve those with appropriate `delims`, sure. Have fun with Unicode file names in console windows with raster fonts, then. It's sort of like asking *»Why would I ever use `Directory.GetFiles` if I could just as well start `cmd /c dir /b` and parse its output?«*

Answer (score 1):

In your question you stated `echo %g%` which is wrong (the trailing `%` will be returned literally).

When the command is directly typed into command prompt, use:

```
for /f "delims=" %g in ('dir /B') do echo %g
```

When you are using `for` within a **batch file** you need double-`%` for its variable:

```
for /f "delims=" %%g in ('dir /B') do echo %%g
```

The option `delims=;` makes no sense as `dir` does not give a semicolon-separated list, so I deactivated `delims`.

The `/B` switch changes the `dir` output to bare format (no headers ad footers, only files and dir.s).

Comment: The error message would have been "g was unexpected at this time." in that case, though.